# startup script is not being executed

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, shell-script, systemd

I'm running Arch Linux and I'm trying to run a script as soon as my server starts. I've created a new file in /etc/systemd/system/ with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Script for booting the thingy

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/start-script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script is made executable with `chmod +x /home/start-script.sh`
Executing it with `bash /home/start-script.sh` works as it should and starts the stuff I want started. I've enabled the startup unit with `systemctl enable start-script`. After a quick reboot, I reconnect through ssh and notice immediately that the script hasn't been executed. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the system logs (journalctl -b) for any error messages related to the script? If not, that's the first thing you're doing wrong.

Comment: What does the script do? Does it need to be run as root or under your own user account? Does it need some user-specific environment variables? Does it expect to be run in a specific directory, like at /home/albert?

Comment: @grawity `journalctl -b` only shows `Started Script for booting the thingy`
The script starts a django app.